# Oven Jerky a Possibility?

Tags: beef, oven, jerky

I was thinking a lot about comments on my posts that claimed that the oven would dry out foods meant to be cooked on a stove.  This got me thinking that I could make beef jerky in the oven.  Any tips, gotchas, or suggestions for oven jerky?

Comment: My mother has our family's beef jerky recipe, and it calls for sticking it in the oven. Unfortunately I don't have the recipe so I can't give you any pointers on how to go about doing it, but I know that it is possible. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it as others have mentioned on the lowest setting, You want a temp around 150 degrees F (65 degrees C). When you do this prepare for drippings. Cut the meat about 50 to 75% thicker than you want the finished product. To thin will turn it into paper. We soak our meat in a soya sause, sugar, garlic & pepper brine. To add different flavor we will add a hot sauce and honey to make a sweet/hot flavor. Let the meat sit over night in the brine at the least. Stir it a few times to make sure it soaks evenly. you should use a metal screen to put the jerky on, it doesn't work well to lay it in a pan. it will just cook in the juices if you do. spray no stick on the screen it helps.

Good luck.

Comment: I will try this over the holiday break and report back.  Sounds delicious!

Comment: I have tried a few different soya sauces and find the best to be China Lilly. Don't add any salt, the sauce leaves it salty enough.

Comment: I am going to reply here and say that although this may not be exactly what jerky is (it is cooked, as well as dried), it has a very similar result both in flavor and texture.  I would suggest that everyone who is wondering whether this works great should try it out.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you will want to use the lowest setting on your oven and have the oven door propped open so the moisture has a place to go and to keep from cooking the meat.

Answer (score 0):

Since jerkey is just dried and salted/ mariated meat it actually isn't supposed to get cooked, so it would be jerkey-like.  But if you put thin strips of meat in the oven on it's lowest setting it would cook it slow enough and take out enough of the mositure to make something like jerky.